# How to subtract two different field date in python?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

I have some problem,
I use python.

I have 2 var, like

```
ads = fields.Date('Admission Date', help='Date of admission')
dds = fields.Date('Discharge Date', help='Date of discharge')
```

I have one var to subtract the date,

```
los=ads-dds
```

but, I have some error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

what should I do to get the result of los?

Comment: *I have some problem, I use python.*. No, you are using Python, that's awesome! Not a problem at all! :-P

Comment: Both values must be the same time. So you need either convert datetime to date or vice versa.

Comment: @user1833746, you mean "must be the same type", don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those fields is a `date` object, the other a `datetime` object. You'll have to decide what you want subtraction to *mean*.

You could, for example, turn the `date` object into a `datetime` object with a fixed time of day, say, midnight:

```
los = ads - datetime.datetime.combine(dds, datetime.time.min)
```

[`datetime.datetime.combine()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) takes a `date` and a `time` object and creates a new `datetime` object; we use [`datetime.time.min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min) as an easy short-cut to a `time` object representing midnight.

Or, you could just turn the `datetime` object into a `date` object and then subtract:

```
los = ads.date() - dds
```

The [`datetime.date()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) returns just the date component of a `datetime` object. The result is a `datetime.timedelta()` object representing the number of days between the two dates.